# Drupal "You are not authorized to access this page."

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm just starting out on drupal, so apologies if this is a really silly question.  I wrote the following module, but every time I try to access it, going to the url (http://localhost:8888/drupal/doodil_viral_signup) I get an access denied message.  I've tried rebuilding the permissions and disabling and re-enabling the module, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php
// $Id$
/**
* @file
* A module to encourage users to sign up.
* This module allows users to sign up to register for the site, and invite their friends to do the same.
*/

/**
* Implements hook_help().
*/
function doodil_viral_signup_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#first') {
    return t('This module allows users to sign up to register for the site, and invite their friends to do the same.');
  }
}

/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function doodil_viral_signup_menu($may_cache = true) {
  $items = array();
  if ($may_cache) {
    $items[] = array(
      'path' => 'doodil_viral_signup',
      'title' => t('Doodil Signup'),
      'callback' => 'doodil_viral_signup_page',
      'access' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
  }
  return $items;
}

function doodil_viral_signup_page() {
  return drupal_get_form('doodil_viral_signup_page_form');
}

function doodil_viral_signup_page_form() {
  // [input text] First Name
  $form['first_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
  );

  // [input text] Last Name
  $form['last_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last Name'),
  );

  // [input text] Email Address
  $form['email_address'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Email Address'),
  );

  // [input submit] Sign Me Up
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#title' => t('Sign Me Up'),
  );
  return $form;
}

function doodil_viral_signup_page_form_submit($form_id, $form_values) {
  $message = 'You have submitted the following information <pre>'.print_r($form_values).'</pre>';
  drupal_set_message(t($message));
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do everything what `loganfsmyth` suggested to you except for the `hook_menu()`, it should be like this:

```
function doodil_viral_signup_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['doodil_viral_signup'] = array(
    'title' => 'Doodil Signup',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('doodil_viral_signup_page_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

And remove `doodil_viral_signup_page()` function.

**EDIT**

This was just tested on my machine and it's working perfect. If it wouldn't work on your machine, then the problem is not in this module.

```
function doodil_viral_signup_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#first') {
    return t('This module allows users to sign up to register for the site,
    and invite their friends to do the same.');
  }
}

function doodil_viral_signup_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['doodil_viral_signup'] = array(
    'title' => 'Doodil Signup',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('doodil_viral_signup_page_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

function doodil_viral_signup_page_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['first_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name')
  );
  $form['last_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last Name')
  );
  $form['email_address'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Email Address')
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Sign Me Up')
  );
  return $form;
}

function doodil_viral_signup_page_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $message = t('Your submitted information <pre>!info</pre>', array(
    '!info' => print_r($form_state['values'], TRUE)
  ));
  drupal_set_message($message);
}
```

Comment: Still nothing :( I've been through the entire module code and made sure I haven't done anything stupid like missing semi-colons (and all the other assorted crap that comes with typing too quickly).

Would either of you be willing to take a closer look at the code and my Drupal installation?  I'm quite happy to give admin access etc.

Answer (score 1):

When your given ($form, &$form_state) in the above code which is given. 
You may be geting this type of error:

```
--------------------------------------
warning: Missing argument 2 for 
--------------------------------------
```

There has to be only one argument in the function.

```
function_name($form)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.

Solved by doing this:
Remove the underscores in: page_callback,page_arguments and access_callback.

They should be "page callback" , "page arguments", "access callback". (no underscores)

Answer (score 0):

This code is all in the format used by Drupal 5. Your tag says drupal 7, so I'm assuming that's what you want?

```
function doodil_viral_signup_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['doodil_viral_signup'] = array(
    'title' => 'Doodil Signup',
    'page callback' => 'doodil_viral_signup_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

And the form should be

```
function doodil_viral_signup_page_form($form, &$form_state) {
```

And the submit should be:

```
function doodil_viral_signup_page_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('You have submitted the following information <pre>!info</pre>', array(
    '!info' => print_r($form_state['values'], TRUE),
  )));
}
```

Using `<pre>` is an ugly way to debug things though. You should download the `devel` module and use it's function `dsm($form_state['values']);`

Comment: Yeah I am using Drupal 7.  Serves me right for using an outdated tutorial!  Even after making the changes you suggested, this still doesn't seem to work though.  I disabled the module, rebuilt the permissions and re-enabled it after making the changes to make sure.

Comment: Actually, I just tried another test page and that says Access Denied as well.  I'm guessing this is a permissions problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by rebuild permissions, but you'll need to click "Clear Cache" on the "Performance" page. Drupal keeps all data from hook_menu in a cache, so hook_menu is only executed when you clear the cache.